# Running Difference between two columns

Tags: sql, sum, case, heidisql

I want to calculate a running-difference when saldo 1 is below saldo 2.

Below you can find my dataset

[image]

I wish to obtain the following result

[image]

I have tried so many things with subqueries and different ways of finding the difference. I have found many examples of running-totals with one value and so. But I cannot get my conditinal statements to work and if I just do the clean code without the conditional statements, my values are always wrong.

Here is my code at the moment. I am using partition as I want to reset when ID change.

```
IF SALDO1 < SALDO2
BEGIN
SELECT ID, SALDO1, SALDO2, 
    SUM(SALDO2 - SALDO1) over (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) as RunningDifference
END

ELSE 
BEGIN 
   '0'  
END

FROM test2;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am doing this in HeidiSQL

Comment: SQL tables don't have a guaranteed order to them. Not even an implicit one. You MUST add another column to use in your ORDER BY if you want to guarantee what order the rows are processed in.

Comment: Thank you! I can see that was my main problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want conditional statements around and within the window sum:

```
select id, saldo1, saldo2, 
    case when saldo1 < saldo2   
        then sum(case when saldo1 < saldo2 then saldo2 - saldo1 else 0 end) 
            over (partition by id order by ordering_id) 
        else 0
    end as runningdifference
from test2
```

If your database supports `greatest()`, we can shorten the inner expression:

```
select id, saldo1, saldo2, 
    case when saldo1 < saldo2   
        then sum(greatest(saldo2 - saldo1, 0)) over (partition by id order by ordering_id) 
        else 0
    end as runningdifference
from test2
```

Note that your `over()` clause is not stable: `partition by id order by id` does not provide a consistent ordering criteria of rows within the partition: all rows are ties, so all end up summed together. You need a deterministic sorting criteria to achieve the result you want, I assumed `ordering_id`.

Comment: Thank you the answer! tried out your code, however it just returns 50 all time and change the place of the 0.

Comment: @Kasper: this is explained in the answer; you need a deterministic `order by` clause.

Comment: So I need to add an extra column to specify the exact order of the order id? I think I understand what you mean. Basically, I need the column specifing what the id is actually about. And use that to order the items. The ID cannot be used for that.

Comment: @Kasper: yes, indeed.

Comment: Thank you. I have to try it out!

Comment: It works. Thank you so much sir! I feel like this post helped me out in multiple cases. Both conditional statements but also how to think about partition and ordering. It really helped me out on many levels

Comment: Can IF statements be used instead of cases ?

Comment: @Kasper: some databases support `if` as a function (not a statement), but I would recommend `case`, which is standard SQL, as showed in the answer.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225596/discussion-between-kasper-and-gmb).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to what the running difference when `saldo2` is greater than `saldo`.  That would be

```
select t.*,
       (case when saldo2 > saldo1
             then sum(case when saldo2 > saldo1 then saldo2 - saldo1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by <ordering column>)
             else 0
        end)
from test2 t;
```

Note that your question presupposes a column that expresses the ordering.  That should be the argument to the `order by`, not `id` (which is used for partitioning).  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies that information.

Comment: Thank you! I can need to add the extra column and try it out!